# How to Identify iAD supported Regions

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iad

I am planning to use **iAD** for my iOS application. As the iAD available only in **USA,UK,France,Italia,Deutschland,España AppStores**.

I want to display iAD only for supported regions. This will avoid displaying "Test Advertisement" from iAD.I can use AdMob for all other regions.

I am not sure, how to identify the iOS Device is used in supported region?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Sasikumar JP

Comment: Have you found out the answer for this question? I am interested to know. For example, is it based on the language or region setting for the device?

Comment: I have not found any way to identify the supported region. i am using fallback approach to handle it. first request goes to iAD, if it fails, i fall back to other ad network.

Answer (score 0):

If your region is not supported, It won't show anything.

Comment: Are you sure about this. iAd is NOT supported in my region. I have seen many application in my device including angry birds shows test ad banner displayed.

Comment: Well it depends where you bought AngryBirds maybe... I'm thinking that maybe you bought your App on AppStore US or some other iAd Country =)

Comment: Or maybe those Apps aren't using iAds but AdMob =P